# duplicate cells in excel automatically via formula or via another method

Tags: excel

I have a question concerning a zip code file.
I have a zipcode in cell 1 (for instance 1234) and a number in the next cell (for instance 4). In this case I want to duplicate my zip code 4 times. So at first I had this:

1234     4

And it has to be

1234
1234
1234
1234

cell 2 does not really matter anymore. They dont have to show the number 1 now that they have been split, as long as my first cell has been duplicated the number of times cell 2 says. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your zip codes are in column A, and the number of repetitions in B, then put this formula in C (drag copy down to the end of your data).

```
=REPT($A1&",",$B1)
```

Then, select all of column C, copy, then paste special its values over itself.

Next, select column C and use the "Text to Columns" tool (Data > Text to Columns). Choose "Delimited", click "Next", and only check next to "Comma". Click "Finish"

Comment: thank you, however, apparantly my post was not presented in the right way. Now, cell c1 has for instance 1234, d1 has 1234, e1 has 1234 etc. It should be c1 has 1234, c2 has 1234, c3 has 1234 etc. They data should still be in 1 colomn but beneath each other instead of next to each other. Is this also possible?